# If my parameter is null I want to set it -sql call

Tags: sql, null

So if my store procedure is called with a null item I want to make it '' (otherwise it won't work with my result list) 
How does one do this?

I would like my code to spit out the population for one country if the country input was US,null,null, or I want it more specific population if US,New York, New York City is put in.  So population of New York City.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[GetPopulation]

        @CountryCode varchar(3),
    @State varchar(80)=null,
    @City varchar(80)=null
as
if @State is Null 
    @State = ''
if @City is Null 
    @City = ''

select Population
FROM Countries
Where CountryCode = @CountryCode AND State = @State AND City=@City
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're seeing and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is Where CountryCode = 'US' AND State = '' AND City='' a valid where clause for your query? Does this return's any rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am right you want to ignore where clause's when parameter is null

```
select Population
FROM Countries
Where (CountryCode = @CountryCode OR @CountryCode IS NULL)
 AND (State = @State OR @State IS NULL)
 AND (City=@City OR @City IS NULL)
```

In case your problem is the application parameters the procedure run's with, then default param's to ''

```
Create procedure [dbo].[GetPopulation]

        @CountryCode varchar(3),
    @State varchar(80)='',
    @City varchar(80)=''

select Population
FROM Countries
Where CountryCode = @CountryCode AND State = @State AND City=@City
```

Run the procedure as `dbo.GetPopulation 'US'` for US or

```
dbo.GetPopulation 'US','New York', 'New York City' for New York City
```

Comment: He's not trying to allow for null @CountryCode.

Comment: Wanted just to demonstrate (Column=@param OR @param IS NULL).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the parameters empty:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
Create procedure [dbo].[GetPopulation]

    @CountryCode varchar(3),
    @State varchar(80)=null,
    @City varchar(80)=null
as
select Population
FROM Countries
Where CountryCode = @CountryCode AND 
    State = coalesce(@State, State) AND 
    City = coalesce(@City, City)
```

Comment: This can still give erroneous results if any of the columns are NULLable and contain NULL values.

Comment: @Tom Only if SET ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF which unfortunately is the default although the native drivers will automatically set it to ON when connecting. Also notice that when creating a procedure (which is the case here) in the SQL Server Management Studio it will include a SET ANSI_NULLS ON. Setting ANSI_NULLS to OFF can create problems when dealing with indexes and will be an error in future versions of SQL Server. I modified the code above to explicitly set it to ON. [Manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: You have it backwards. The ANSI standard (`SET ANSI_NULLS ON`) considers all NULL comparisons (= or <>) to equate to unknown. Further, even with `ANSI_NULL` set to `OFF`, my test this morning shows that the coalesce method will still not return rows with NULL values in the column.

Comment: @Tom Yes, _'The ANSI standard (SET ANSI_NULLS ON) considers all NULL comparisons (= or <>) to equate to unknown'_ so the query as is will not return any rows with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
set @State = coalesce(@State, '')
```

The [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) operator will return the first non-null value.  In this case, either @state or ''

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question -- just fix your WHERE clause like this:

```
   WHERE      
             CountryCode = @CountryCode 
         AND (State = @State OR @State is null) 
         AND (City = @City OR @City is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

@State varchar(80) = null --> this means "allow the procedure to run without the @State parameter"
@State varchar(80) = '' --> this means "if the procedure is run without the @State parameter, then change the @State parameter to '' (empty string).

Option 2 is doing the same thing as this, so you can delete this section:

```
if @State is Null 
    @State = ''
if @City is Null 
    @City = ''
```

The only other thing is to fix your WHERE clause to handle missing parameter values (which is hopefully self-explanatory when you see it below).

So then this is your original code, fixed per the explanation above:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[GetPopulation]

    @CountryCode varchar(3),
    @State varchar(80)='',
    @City varchar(80)=''
as

select Population
FROM Countries
Where CountryCode = @CountryCode AND (State = @State OR @State = '') AND (City=@City OR @City = '')
```